# Can I include C file in PHP Code?

Tags: php

I was wondering, as I was on [this repository](https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zbarcode/tree/master/tests) the test case includes a `skipif.inc.php` file that has these two lines of code:

```php
if (!extension_loaded('zbarcode')) {
    die("Skip.");
}
```

and the 'zbarcodes' file is a `.C` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `zbarcode` is a compiled PHP extension. Maybe it has the same name as the .C file in that particular project, but `extension_loaded` does not check if C files are loaded, only if a compiled PHP extension is loaded and ready for use.

So the answer to your question would be: No, you cannot.

EDIT: A lot of C projects have a C file of the same name where the "main" routines are stored, so this is where the confusion is coming from.

You need to build that project (it becomes a .dll on windows and .so on *nix) and then load it either via the PHP ini or [`dl()`](http://php.net/dl).